# Solving differential equations numerically using Arduino

Tags: arduino, cortex-m3

Is it possible to use an Arduino/Arduino Mega or a Maple (STM32 based board) to perform realtime numerical integration using a Runge Kutta algorithm(for simple physics simulations)?

If not would the addition of a FPU coprocessor like the uM-FPU v3.1 make it possible?

Comment: Yep, it's possible.

Comment: Your question belongs on a programming site. This is a question about computation, and not about sensors or I/O or actuators (in which case this site would be OK)

Comment: @Jason S Sorry about asking it in the wrong site, this is related to another question I asked about hardware on this site and I forgot that this site doesn't cover programming (then again this doesn't belong at Stackoverflow either). Do you want me to delete it?

Comment: Hmm. well, now that I think about it, maybe I was a bit harsh. if you provided some quantitative information (e.g. how many state variables, max. frequencies) and wanted to know if your CPU could meet computational throughput, that might be appropriate here... but I don't think you'd get an answer here, and even maybe not on SO. Math.stackexchange.com maybe? (but if so, leave out the hardware requirements, and ask how to figure out how much CPU power you need) Don't delete the question.

Answer (score 3):

As @tyblu already noted, yes, it's possible.

Of course, it depends what you mean by "realtime", and how accurate results you want. Another possibility - depending on your system - may be offloading calculations to host computer (Arduino reads inputs, writes numbers to serial (or wirelessly with xbee, for example), computer calculates whatever you want to calculate and prints results to Arduino, and then Arduino decides what it'll do (change outputs)).

Comment: The results needn't be that accurate it is just for demonstration of various types of motion graphically on an oscilloscope.From simple bouncing balls to those involving springs and pendulums. Like those listed at http://www.myphysicslab.com/ I want the unit to run standalone so what what you recommend for the microcontroller.

Comment: @Alexdagre8 Make your question more specific, then.

Comment: @Alexdagre8, the integration isn't a big deal; note that there are other faster methods than Runge Kutta. Concentrate on your display requirements, which will take up the bulk of the micro's resources.

Answer (score 1):

I am achieving around 1000 simulation steps per second with a runge-kutta-integrator with a system with 4 state variables. If this suits your requirements, you should be fine.
See https://hmbd.wordpress.com/2015/04/11/numerical-integration-of-a-differential-equation-on-an-arduino-using-the-runge-kutta-method/ for the arduino sketch.

Answer (score 0):

What about analog computer?

You can buy discrete integrators and multipliers and have output directly available for oscilloscope in real time.

The downside of that is that, as far as I can see, actual analog computer components tend to be expensive and rare these days, so you might be forced to make them yourself using mostly op-amps (which will have negative impact on accuracy) and that you'd have to make a new circuit for each equation you want to solve. Still, they are definitely the fastest solution because they work at speed of propagation of electrical signal.

A positive side it that on analog computers it is pretty obvious how everything works and how equation gets turned into electrical signal. Plus you get to use lots of really cool potentiometers too!

Comment: My original plan was to build an analogue computer but I couldn't find any information on how to build one from scratch using modern components, so this is an attempt to mimic such a system digitally. A hybrid design where the analogue circuit (or at least the parameters) could be altered with a microcontroller/FPGA would be ideal, but it's just a dream for now.